# Travelling to Cyprus do I need to renew passport

Tags: passports

My passport runs out April 17. I'm going Oct 29-Nov 9  I'll have 4 months left on passport when returning, do I have to renew before I go ?

Comment: Which country issued your passport?

Comment: Where are you returning to?

Answer (score 1):

google says that for EU visitors the passport must be valid for the duration of the stay, and that for non-EU visitor, it must be valid 3 months to the date of departure.

http://www.worldtravelguide.net/cyprus/passport-visa

Comment: The first part of the sentence does not really make sense: EU citizens don't have to say how long they want to stay or to provide any evidence regarding their date of return so what is "duration of stay" supposed to mean in this context? Also, EU citizens can visit Cyprus or reside their with a national ID card as well (i.e. without a passport). The second part of your answre does address the question however.

Comment: @Relaxed, I'd read it that EU citizens need a valid identity document at all times. If it runs out while they're there, how do they prove that freedom of movement applies?

Comment: @o.m. I think it's actually that they need a valid *travel* document, though the distinction is admittedly monor and your basic point holds.  To answer your question, if it runs out while they're there, they prove their freedom of movement rights by applying for a replacement document at the appropriate consulate.  It would obviously be better for those staying for a short time to renew the document before traveling, but the asker of this question seems to be fine whether or not his passport is from the EU.

Comment: Aside from 'World Travel Guide' what do the EU regulations say about this situation? That would be a more defensible link, no?

Comment: @o.m They renew it of course. That's completely unrelated to entry requirements... Speaking of a document “valid for the duration of stay“ implies that you must know/prove how long you will stay and have a document valid for that duration *when you enter*. If there is a requirement to hold ID while they are within the country, it's up to the EU citizen to make sure they don't fall foul of it (and even if they do, they risk a fine, not removal) but all you may have to prove at the point of entry is that you are indeed an EU citizen.

Comment: Can you please quote from the URL, in case the link changes or is down when someone needs it?